# C# from what direction is the sound coming?

Tags: c#

I am searching for a C# library to look where the sound of my output (speakers) is coming from. I think its called a spectrum analyzer? Does anybody know a good library?

thnx!

Comment: From drums, guitar voice etc? Or from which program in windows?

Comment: #wow thats a research level topic..

Answer (score 0):

What usually you can do is have 3 or four mics facing each direction and then analyse the higher decibles or loudness and detect (resolve) direction

I think [this article at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WAVE_Processor_In_CSharp.aspx) can help you getting started.
it has codes for processing wav files.

Answer (score 0):

3D sounds like something common in gaming. 
http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/3d_audio